# Modifying and reloading html

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I include a HTML page in my principal page using Iframe. I modify the content of the new included HTML page.

Actually, I just include a Javascript library which I created. But this library contains some functions which execute before the page is loaded.

But since I modify the new HTML page contents after loading, these variables in my library are NaN. How can I solve this? Is there any way I can reload the modified content, or any way I can access the document before loading it?

I tried:

```
document.getElementById("test").contentWindow.location.reload(true);
```

... but this reloads the unmodified IFrame content.

```
<html> 
    <head> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

        <style>
            iframe { height : 100%; width : 100%; border : 0px; overflow: auto; float : left; }
        </style>  

        <script>
            window.onload = function() {
                var fileref=document.createElement('script');
                fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
                fileref.setAttribute("src", "resizeEjquery.js");

                file=document.getElementById("test");
                y=file.contentDocument;
                y.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(fileref);

                /*document.getElementById("test").contentWindow.location.reload(true);*/
            }
        </script>

    </head> 

    <body> 
        <iframe id="test" src="teste1.html"></iframe> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you are using jQuery:**

You can manually fire method exeting all what was in onLoad

```
$(window).load();
```

Fire load function in frame using jQuery

```
$($('#test').contentWindow).load();
```

**Without jQuery:**

You can also access iframe functions by

```
document.getElementById("test").contentWindow.functioName();
```

Comment: @Powertieke he use something like resizeEjquery.js, it look like jquery.

Comment: resizeEjquery includes jquery in this

Comment: but how can i manually fire $(window).load in the iframe content ?

Comment: From parent window $($('#test').contentWindow).load();

Comment: But i havent defined jquery for my principal web page and for political reasons i cant include  jquery in my principa page ..

Comment: Create reLoad() {$(window).load(); } in  frame then, document.getElementById("test").contentWindow.reLoad();

Comment: Sorry , but i got an error " document.getElementById("test").contentWindow.reLoad is not a function " \

Comment: hey igor, i cannot add any content to new html page in Iframe. However i can modify by javascript library.